# Facebook app using js sdk supporting multiple websites via CMS

Tags: javascript, facebook

We have a CMS system with a couple thousand dealers websites powered by it. On their sites, we want to allow certain content to be shareable to a FB user's wall if they so choose. To do this, we'd use the FB Javascript SDK.

Looking at the app creation process, it has a requirement for a url to be specified. We have thousands of urls that could be associated. Is it possible to use a single "App" instance across all the url's without specifing each one?

Comment: This has been asked before … http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=facebook+app+multiple+domains

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the simplest approach to sharing web page content on Facebook is to implement FB's Open Graph Markup on pages intended to be shared. Details on Open Graph Markup can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web